# HTML and CSS website: move headers, add comment box

Tags: html, css

So I have to create a website using notepad++ and coding in HTML and CSS.

I have 4 different files and want to move the headings to the left so they are in line with the other text.

I was wondering if you guys could help me out with that.

I also want to make it look professional and visually appealing. Where should I go to learn how to do that?

I also want to add a comment box where a customer can comment and it will show up in the webpage. Please help.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Playthrough Gaming Cafe</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="playthrough.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Playthrough Gaming Cafe</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
  <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<main>
<div id="gaminglogo"></div>
<h2>Playthrough Gaming Cafe</h2>
<p>We&#39;re located on the corner of Roosevelt Rd and Westchester Rd. Come level up your gaming experience at Playthrough!</p>
<h3>Playthrough Gaming Cafe features:</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Adult Zone with fully stocked bar for customers 21+!</li>
  <li>Teen Zone with Snack Bar!</li>
  <li>Old Generation Gaming Room!</li>
  <li>Multitude of systems and tvs.!</li>
  <li>Open Late on weekends and holidays.</li>
</ul>
<div>
3453 Westchester RD<br>
WestChester IL 60189<br>
<a id="mobile" href="tel:888-599-5959">888-599-5959</a> <span id="desktop">888-599-5959</span><br><br>
</div>
</main>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2016 Playthrough Gaming Cafe<br>
<a href="mailto:kennypatel@gmail.com">kennypatel@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

menu.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Playthrough Game Cafe</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="playthrough.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Playthrough Gaming Cafe</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
  <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<main>
<div id="videogamesshelf"></div>
<h2>Gaming at Playthrough</h2>
<p>Come and play your favorite games at Playthrough. We have all the old classic systems and also the new current. Rent out some games, play before buy, and also indulge in some beverages at our very own Playthrough Cafe. </p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Playthrough Gaming</th>
      <td>We have all the game systems and more than enough tvs to play them. From Nintendo NES to Xbox One Slim, we have it all.<br>Entry Fee: $15.00 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Playthrough Cafe</th>
      <td> Come enjoy our robust and smooth coffee, energy drinks, and soda. <br>Can: $0.75 Bottle: $1.25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Playthrough Adult</th>
      <td>We have a seperate area for customer's 21+ with a fully stocked bar.<br>Entry Fee: $25. </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</main>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2016 Playthrough Gaming Cafe<br>
<a href="mailto:kennypatel@gmail.com">kennypatel@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

jobs.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Playthrough Gaming Cafe Jobs</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="playthrough.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Playthrough Gaming Cafe</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
  <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<main>
<h2>Jobs at Playthrough Gaming Cafe</h2>
<p>Want to work at JavaJam? Fill out the form below to start your application. Required fields are
marked with an asterisk (*).</p>
<form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/javajam8.php">
<label for="myName">*Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="myName" name="myName" required="required">
<label for="myEmail">*E-mail: </label>
<input type="email" id="myEmail" name="myEmail" required="required">
<label for="myExperience">*Experience: </label>
<textarea name="myExperience" id="myExperience" rows="2" cols="20" required="required"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Apply Now">
</form>
</main>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2016 Playthrough Gaming Cafe<br>
<a href="mailto:kennypatel@gmail.com">kennypatel@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

feedback.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Playthrough Gaming Cafe</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="playthrough.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Playthrough Gaming Cafe</h1>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
  <li><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<main>
<div id="gaminglogo"></div>
<h2>Leave us some feedback at Playthrough Gaming Cafe</h2>
<p>Every week we hold a brainstorming session where we look at the feedback from customers. WE are here to CATER YOUR NEEDS!.</p>
<p>We are a new company, and we want gamers to have a place where they feel safe. Please leave some feedback what YOU, the customer thinks would help us deliver the best gaming experience.</p>
<form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/javajam8.php">
<label for="myName">*Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="myName" name="myName" required="required">
<label for="myEmail">*E-mail: </label>
<input type="email" id="myEmail" name="myEmail" required="required">
<label for="myComment">*Feedback: </label>
<textarea name="myComment" id="myComment" rows="2" cols="20" required="required"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Post Feedback!">
</form>


</main>
<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2016 Playthrough Gaming Cafe<br>
<a href="mailto:kennypatel@gmail.com">kennypatel@gmail.com</a>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

playthrough.css

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; }
header, nav, main, footer {display: block; }


body { background-color: FFFFFF;
  background-image: url(Blue-Background.gif);
  color: #67D9E3;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-image: url(Blue-Background.gif);
}
#wrapper { background-color: #0E828C;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left:auto;
   max-width: 1280px;
   min-width: 900px;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666666;
   width: 80%
}
header {background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url(gaminglogo.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 150px;
}
h1 { padding-top: 45px;
 padding-left: 220px;
 font-size: 3em;
 text-align: left;
}

nav { text-align: center; 
     font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
nav a {text-decoration: none;}
nav a:visited{ color: #1EEDED; }
nav a:link { color: #08BB17; }
nav a:hover { color: #7F30BC; }
nav ul {list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;}
footer{ background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: small;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center; 
  border-top: 2px #221811 solid;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
main {padding: 0 0 2 em 0;
  margin-left: 200px;
  background-color:1EEDED; 
}
main h2, main h3 main h4, main p, main div, main ul, main dl {padding-left: 3em; 
 padding-right: 2em; }
h4 {background-color: #2678B3;
    font-size: 1.2em;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000033;
 clear: left;
}
img {padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;}
.details {padding-right: 20%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  overflow: auto;}
.floatleft {float:left;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px; }
#videogamesshelf {background-size: 80% 80%;
   background-image: url(videogamesshelf.jpg);
   height: 250px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   margin: auto; 
   width: 50%;
}
#gamehead {background-size: 80% 80%;
   background-image: url(gaminglogo.jpg);
   height: 250px;
   width: 50%
   
}
#videogameheart{background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-image: url(videogameheart.png);
   height: 250px;}
#mobile { display: none; }
#desktop { display: inline; }
table { width: 90%;
      margin: auto;
   border-spacing: 0;
   background-color: #FFFFCC; }
td, th { padding: 10px; }
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #0E828C; }
form { padding: 2em; }
label { float: left;
      display: block;
   text-align: right;
    width: 8em;
    padding-right: 1em; }
input, textarea { display: block; margin-bottom: 1em; }
#mySubmit { margin-left: 9.5em; }
audio { display: block; margin-top: 1em; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 body { background-image: none; }
 #wrapper { width: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: none;  }
 header { border-bottom: 5px solid #DAF6F2; }
 h1 { margin-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 2.5em;  }
 nav { float: none;
       width: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3em;  }
 nav li  { display: inline-block; }
 nav a { padding: 1em; 
       width: 8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-style: none; }
 nav ul { padding: 0;
        margin: 0; }
 #videogamesshelf,#gamehead ,#videogameheart{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
 main { padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
    font-size: 90%; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 header { background-image: url(gamingmonkey.jpg); 
   height: 128px; }
 h1 { font-size: 2em;
      text-align: center;
   padding-left: 0; }
 nav { margin: 0; }
 nav a { display: block;
        padding: 0.2em;
     width: auto;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #FEF6C2; }
 nav li { display: block; }
 main  { padding-top: 1px; }
 h2 { padding: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
     margin-right: 0.5em; }
 .details { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; }
 #videogamesshelf,#gamehead,#videogameheart { background-image: none; height: auto; } 
 .floatleft { padding-left: 0.5em; padding-right: 0.5em; }
 #mobile { display: inline; }
 #desktop { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: The headings _are_ in line with the rest of the text. Did you mean the list items you wanted to align?

Comment: WRT "look professional and visually appealing", that is a matter of opinion, which is off-topic on this site.